# How to get a developer access code for Samsung Health developer mode?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-health

https://developer.samsung.com/health/android/data/guide/dev-mode.html#How-to-Activate-the-Developer-Mode

How the heck do you get an Access code? They say you need a "partnership." What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation: https://developer.samsung.com/health/android/data/guide/process.html

> **Note :**
> We are currently going through an update to better support our partners. For that reason, we will not be accepting any applications for the Partner Apps Program at this time.

So for now this documentation exists for existing partners, looks like we can't join in yet ;) Otherwise you should contact their support lines: https://developer.samsung.com/support or even try posting in their community forum before you post on SO.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I missed that note.